# Illegal Start of Type and ";" Expected

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax-error

I'm trying to write a program here and I first started off with 23 errors, I managed to get it down to 7 errors but have no idea how to get rid of them at all. The error messages are as follows:

```
Exercise1Lab5.java:58: error: illegal start of type
        else
        ^
Exercise1Lab5.java:58: error: ';' expected
        else
            ^
Exercise1Lab5.java:59: error: illegal start of type
                System.out.println("\nYou Are Either Too Old or Too Young!");
                      ^
Exercise1Lab5.java:59: error: ';' expected
                System.out.println("\nYou Are Either Too Old or Too Young!");
                          ^
Exercise1Lab5.java:59: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
                System.out.println("\nYou Are Either Too Old or Too Young!");
                           ^
Exercise1Lab5.java:59: error: illegal start of type
                System.out.println("\nYou Are Either Too Old or Too Young!");
                                   ^
Exercise1Lab5.java:65: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
7 errors
```

My Code Is:

```
/**
 * @(#)Exercise1Lab5.java
 *
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2014/11/3
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise1Lab5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    float age, height, weight;
    String genderAns, recordAns, certAns, courseAns;
    char y, n, m, f;

    System.out.print("\nPlease Enter Your Age: ");
    age = input.nextFloat();

    if(age>=18 && age<35){
        System.out.print("\nPlease Enter Your Height: ");
        height = input.nextFloat();

        if(height>=1.6){
            System.out.print("\nPlease Enter Your Weight In 'KG': ");
            weight = input.nextFloat();

            if(weight>=100){    
                System.out.print("\nPlease Enter Your Gender <m or f>?: ");
                genderAns = input.nextLine();

                if(((genderAns.equals('m')) && (weight<100) && (height>=1.85)) || ((genderAns.equals('f')) && (weight<100) && (height>=1.6))){ 
                    System.out.print("\nDo You Have A Criminal Record <y or n>?: ");
                    recordAns = input.nextLine();

                    if(recordAns.equals('n'))
                        System.out.print("\nDid You Receive At Least A D Grade In Pass Irish In The Leaving Cert <y or n>?: ");
                        certAns = input.nextLine();

                        System.out.print("\nDo You Commit To Taking A 10-Week Irish Course on Application <y or n>?: ");
                        courseAns = input.nextLine();
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("\nYou Cannot Have A Criminal Record!");
                }
                else
                System.out.println("\nThus Far You Do Not Meet The Requirements!"); 
            }
            else
                System.out.println("\nYou Need To Be Under 100KG In Weight!");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("\nYou Are Not Tall Enough!");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("\nYou Are Either Too Old or Too Young!");




    }
}
```

If anyone could shed some light on these errors and help me out, I would really appreciate it, thanks!!

Comment: There's a `{` missing after the inner-most `if`. Closing for typo.

Comment: This is yet another good argument for "always use curly braces, even if there is only one statement in the block".

Comment: Learn about DeMorgan's rule and rewrite your code to look like `if (failureCondition) { failure message; return; }` instead of this awful flock-of-seagulls if statement nesting.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I like to minimize the number of return points, just out of personal preference, but early returns are fine as long as it's clear what is happening.

Comment: I don't like many return points, but they are preferable to the hijinks that will happen if he ever has to restructure the logic.  In this case, he could replace much of his logic with `float value = getFloatFailingIfNotInRange(float low, float high, String prompt, String failMessage)`

Comment: I'm only a beginner so I don't know more than what I am currently doing unfortunately.

Comment: @alannm37 Well, welcome to programming.  You will spend a lot of time hunting down "beginner" type "bugs" (or problems).  However, after some time you won't be hunting down so many of these types of bugs.  You'll then hunt down "intermediate" type bugs.  After more time, you'll be hunting down "expert" type bugs.  If there's something that programming will never run out of, it seems that programming will never run out of bugs (just kidding).  Have fun and (at least for starters) focus on making your code easily understood by you and others.  If it reads easily, it will be easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are mismatched. Here:

```
if(recordAns.equals('n'))
    System.out.print("\nDid You Receive At Least A D Grade In Pass Irish In The Leaving Cert <y or n>?: ");
    certAns = input.nextLine();
```

You need a `{` after that `if`.

Sometimes these errors can be confusing. Some tips:

1. Start at the line the error is reported on and carefully work backwards, checking for subtle problems.
2. Use a decent editor that can show you matched brackets. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a good choice for a basic editor.
3. If your editor supports auto-indentation, turn it on. You can catch things like this by spotting problems with the indentation.

You could also sometimes consider restructuring of the code, if possible, to clarify it a bit. For example, if you want to *insist* that your entered age is in range:

```
do {
    System.out.print("\nPlease Enter Your Age: ");
    age = input.nextFloat();
} while (age < 18 || age >= 35);
```

After that block of code, it's guaranteed that `age >= 18 && age < 35`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and tips! I managed to get it running after putting in the missing curly brace and there was also a bracket missing so I fixed that too. But now when I run the program, this happens:

"Please Enter Your Age: 18

Please Enter Your Height: 1.9

Please Enter Your Weight In 'KG': 60

Please Enter Your Gender <m or f>?:
Thus Far You Do Not Meet The Requirements!"

It's just skipping inputting the "m or f" option....

Comment: @alannm37 If you've solved the problem in this post and are having a new problem, please post a new question; but make sure your problem statement is clear and make sure to show us your debugging attempts!

Comment: I can't post another for 90 minutes, but I will then.

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to change like this :

```
if(recordAns.equals('n')) {
                        System.out.print("\nDid You Receive At Least A D Grade In Pass Irish In The Leaving Cert <y or n>?: ");
                        certAns = input.nextLine();

                        System.out.print("\nDo You Commit To Taking A 10-Week Irish Course on Application <y or n>?: ");
                        courseAns = input.nextLine();

}
```